# Adding to a HashSet when it is the value of a HashMap

Tags: java, graph, nullpointerexception, hashmap, hashset

I'm doing an ''generic class'' exercise from my textbook right now, trying to implement a Graph data structure using a HashMap as the underlying structure, with keys being nodes in the Graph, and the values of the keys being a HashSet of the nodes adjacent to that node. The beginning of the code looks like this:

```
   public class Graph <T> {

       public HashMap<T, HashSet<T>> foo_graph;
       //... Code ...
```

I must mention, both the keys and values in the HashSet must be the same type, this is the reason for the T placeholder. With all my methods written out, I'm trying to test this with a `static void main` block, but Eclipse keeps giving me `NullPointerExceptions` whenever I try to print the Graph (which has a working ToString method already given to me):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

Graph<Integer> g = new Graph<>();
        g.addNode(5, [5,3,7]); //Trying to add 5,3,7 to the HashSet, but Eclipse is saying I can't do this.
        System.out.println(g); 
    }
```

This is my addNode method by the way, I can't seem to add anything the Graph either.

```
public void addNode(T node_key, HashSet<T> node_value ) {
            main_graph.put(node_key, node_value);
```

Eclipse is telling me at the addNode line in my static void testing block that:

```
 The method addNode(Integer, HashSet<Integer>) in the type Graph<Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (int, int, int, int)
```

Does anyone know why this is? I just can't seem to get it working, I'm stumped. Neither creating a

Comment: You guys all answered so quick...this is why I love StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  The syntax of putting stuff in square brackets like you've done just doesn't exist.  I have found that the easiest way to initialise a `HashSet` is with the `Arrays.asList` static method.  I would write something like this.

```
g.addNode(5, new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(5, 3, 7)));
```

Comment: I see, I see. Thank you very much, would you know how to append to the same HashSet after it has been inputted into the HashMap like that though?

Comment: Yes, I would know this.  If you look at the Javadocs for the `Set` interface, at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html, you'll find a couple of methods for adding things to `Set` objects.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with Eclipse. You can't do this:

```
g.addNode(5, [5,3,7]);
```

Java won't know how `[5,3,7]` is magically turning into a HashSet.

What you can do is this:

```
HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(5);
set.add(3);
set.add(7);
g.addNode(5, set);
```

Comment: I'd probably do Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(5,3,7));, personally.

Comment: I would personally use Guava's ImmutableSet.of(), but I'm starting slow here :) Looking at his declaration `public HashMap<T, HashSet<T>> foo_graph;`, not sure your suggestion would even work, given the map is of type `<HashSet>`...

Comment: Both of these answers make a lot of sense! Thank you for pointing out my errors, as you can tell, I'm quite new to Java :P